# How to make Sublime Text highlight left bar area on active code block

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text-3, ide, sublime-text

Sometimes I feel lost while coding on Sublime Text as it doesn't highlight the left bar as other IDEs/text editors do.
What I am talking about is the light violet color on line numbers as in Eclipse:

[image: eclipse]

But in Sublime Text, in the end, there's only a small dash beneath curly braces, no line number highlight:

[image: sublime text image]

Is there any way I can get this in Sublime Text?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can place it into your user preferences settings file -

To highlight the entire line (not exactly what you want, but available):

```
"highlight_line": true
```

You can change the color of the highlight with hex values

```
<key>lineHighlight</key>
<string>hexcolor</string>
```

Comment: it made no difference.

Comment: @user3452098 it works in sublime text 2, it should work in 3. I think it only works if you don't have anything selected (or highlighted) in the line. Try it with another theme maybe?

Comment: I have added it in end of user preference like `{
 "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Dawn.tmTheme",
 "font_size": 10,
 "ignored_packages":
 [
  "jQuery"
 ],
 "update_check": false,
 "highlight_line": true
}` am I correct ?

Comment: its a good preference, but not sufficient for what OP asking.